# PyTest parameterizing fixtures? How to split a big test function into several

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

So I have this code:

```
import create_account2
import functions as f

#Import create_account2
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def create_account():
    create = create_account2.hook
    return create

@pytest.mark.usertest
class CreateAccountLoginCUpdateDetailsAndVerify

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('country', ['US', 'UK', "CA"])
    def test_CreateAccountUpdateDetailsAndVerify(self, create_account, country):

        ##Create account
        data = create_account(country)

        ##Login with account
        f.go_to_site(country)
        f.user_login(data['Mail'], data['Password'])
        assert "buttonLogOut" in f.get_driver().page_source, "No logout button so login failed"

        ##Get the original object, before updates..
        OriginalCustomerObject = f.GetDetails(data)

        f.update_details(data)  

        UpdatedCustomerObject = f.GetDetails(data)

        ##Compare objects
        f.CompareData(OriginalCustomerObject, UpdatedCustomerObject)

        ##Quit
        f.quit()
```

So what it does is create an account on the US/UK/CA website with Selenium, get the customer object from the API, update the customer details (adress, phone, etc) via Selenium then retrieve another customer object and compare the original and updated customer objects to make sure that updating user details via the site actually works

So this is all fine. The problem is, I've had to put the account creation, the account updating and the verification of the two objects inside the same test. To parameterize the function with country = [US, UK, CA] seems like a great idea since I don't have to duplicate code. But I can't actually use a fixture then can I? It doesn't seem like you can parameterize fixtures in this way?

So ideally the account creation, account updating of details and verification that the two objects differ would be three dfferent tests? The question is only how I can pass the data properly around. From my beginners understanding of PyTest this should be done with fixtures but in this case that doesn't seem to work.

So should I rather have three tests? TestUS, TestCA, TestUK?

Answer (score 2):

My apologies if I understood your question wrong.

As far as my understanding goes, you cannot pass a value to pytest fixtures like a regular function. With that said, you can use pytest fixture factory pattern to achieve the implementation you are going for.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def create_account():
    def _create_account(country):
        return country

    return _create_account


class TestCreateAccountLoginCUpdateDetailsAndVerify:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('country', ['US', 'UK', 'CA'])
    def test_create_account_update_details_and_verify(self, create_account, country):
        data = create_account(country)
        print(data)

# output
================================================== 3 passed in 0.01s ==================================================
collected 3 items
.US
.UK
.CA
```